# Google Colab x Gitlab Repository cloning problem

Tags: gitlab, google-colaboratory, clone

I am trying to clone my repository in Gitlab to Google Colab but kept receiving this below error. Google Colab has no issue with Github project cloning but Gitlab doesn't seem work.

Cloning into '<project_name>'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See https://gitlab.com/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/<user_name>/<project_name>.git/'

I have read all the related threads on Stackoverflow, trying both deploy_token and personal access token method but neither worked. Below is the line I use:

!git clone https://:@gitlab.com/<user_name>/<project_name>.git